# Instant run Android studio 2.2 I never get hotswap always restart and the notification Field Type Change

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2, android-instant-run

I just updated to Android studio 2.2 and while before I could get hot-swaps when just changing a value of a field or other small things now I always get the restart with the notification: Instant Run applied code changes and restarted the app. Field Type Change.

Even though I haven't changed the type of any fields.

Anyone seen this before? Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: did you review the config for the hot-swap feature in settings for 2.2 in case the upgrade overwrites the prior config setting for HS?

Comment: No, good idea though , where can I find that?

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/A_Guide_to_using_Instant_Run_in_Android_Studio_2#Enabling_and_Disabling_Instant_Run

Comment: Ok, you meant that, no , no changes :(

Comment: I'm having the same issue. What's your target sdk?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, target sdk is 22 currently, don't know if it was when I was having the issue back then how come? My solution was to revert back to android studio 2.1 xD Are people still having problems in 2.2 and moving forward?